# How to show dx gridview total (summary item) on final page only?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

Below is my simplified `gridview`

Currently, the summary is shown on every page. But the client needs the total on the final page only. (Or even better having the total amount of the "page" on each page, and one total of all pages on the final page).

Any help is really appreciated :)

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GrdMain" ClientInstanceName="GrdMain" runat="server" 
        KeyFieldName="AgentAccountSummaryId" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Debit" VisibleIndex="6" UnboundType="Decimal">
            <FooterCellStyle ForeColor="Brown" />
            <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="c0" />
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>

    <Settings ShowFooter="True" />
    <TotalSummary>
        <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="Debit" SummaryType="Sum"/>
    </TotalSummary>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Update**: Here is all I do in Code behind (in `Page_Load`):

```
GrdMain.SettingsPager.PageSize = 25;
GrdMain.ForceDataRowType(typeof(SomeTypeView));
GrdMain.DataSource = GetListOfSomeType();
GrdMain.DataBind();
```

I should also add that I am using `DevExpress GridView`

Comment: You need to create paging logic and post that code.

Answer (score 1):

ASPX page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" PageSize="3" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="fname" SortExpression="fname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="vote" HeaderText="vote" SortExpression="vote" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectDB %>" 
    onselected="SqlDataSource1_Selected" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblA]" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind :

```
decimal RowCount;
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pageSize = GridView1.PageSize;
    decimal totalPages = Math.Ceiling(RowCount / pageSize);

    int TotalAllPage=0;
    int TotalPerPage=0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TotalPerPage += int.Parse( row.Cells[2].Text);
    }
    DataView dView = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataTable dTable = dView.ToTable();
    foreach (DataRow item in dTable.Rows)
    {
        TotalAllPage += int.Parse(item[2].ToString());
    }

    if (GridView1.PageIndex + 1 == totalPages)
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = "Total all page:" + TotalAllPage;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = "Total this page:" + TotalPerPage;
    }
}
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    RowCount = e.AffectedRows; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm using `DevExpress GridView`, and I'm not sure how to adjust your code. (For example, my grid does not have a definition for `.Rows`)